# Concat 2 columns in a string, then get a count for each concatenation

Tags: mysql

I am trying to concatenate 2 columns, then count the number of rows i.e. the total number of times the merged column string exists, but I don't know if it is possible. e.g:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(column_1,':',column_2 ) as merged_columns, 
    COUNT(merged_columns) 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY merged_columns DESC
```

**Note:** the colon I've inserted as a part of the string, so my result is something like 12:3. The 'count' then should tell me the number of rows that exist where column_1 =12 and column_2 = 3.

Obviously, it tells me 'merged_columns' isn't a column as it's just an alias for my CONCAT. But is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Why don't you just `GROUP BY column1, column2`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't give me a count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a temp table from your concatenation select and then query that:

```
SELECT CONCAT(column_1,':',column_2 ) AS mergedColumns
INTO #temp
FROM table 

SELECT COUNT(1) AS NumberOfRows,
   mergedColumns
FROM #temp
GROUP BY mergedColumns
```

Hope this answer is what your are looking for.

Comment: I don't know why,  but your way didn't work, but it did give me the idea to create a temporary first e.g. ``CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tablename SELECT * etc`` and then query the temp table. So thanks!

Comment: I already try it dunno why it doesn't work with you anyway you are welcome.

Answer (score 9):

Old question I know, but the following should work without a temp table (unless I am missing something):

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(column_1,':',column_2 ) as merged_columns, 
    COUNT(CONCAT(column_1,':',column_2 )) 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY merged_columns DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(column_1,column_2 ) as merged_columns, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY merged_columns
ORDER BY merged_columns DESC
```

Comment: Please use backticks ``` around your code to get your code better formatted.

Comment: formatted this, thanks!